# NSManagedObject changes memory address?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a transient, transformable property set for my MO subclass [`FeedItem`], and in a category, I provide lazy loaded access:

```
- (id)images
{
    if (!self.sImages) {
        self.sImages = [[self.imageEntitiesClass alloc] initWithModel:self];
    }
    return self.sImages;
}

- (void)setImages:(id)images
{
    self.sImages = images;
}
```

Now, within `-[FeedItem.managedObjectContext performBlock:]` I call `-[FeedItem prefetchImages]`. What that does, is performs the following call stack:

```
-[FeedItem prefetchImages]
-[FeedItemImages avatar]
-[FeedItem avatarURL]
- MULTI-THREAD ASSERTION
```

Within `-[FeedItemImages avatar]` method, I call `self.model.avatarURL`, but by checking the debugger, `self.model.managedObjectContext` is different from the encapsulating MOC, so it makes sense that the assertion is triggered .. but, why is the MOC different? I explicitly pass `self` in the `-[FeedItemImages init]`, so they should be the same object?

To confirm this issue, I have disabled the caching, and returned a new object every time, and the app worked great:

```
- (id)images
{
#warning TODO - underlying object is changing randomly?
    /** For some weird reason, when we cache image entities, then attempt to
     *  retrieve an image, we sometimes trigger a multithreading assertions 
     *  breakpoint. Debugger shows the owner of the image entity is different
     *  from the model the image entity is referencing ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
     *
     *  Possible solutions:
     *  The Bad:
     *  Current solution. Easy, but very ineffecient.
     *  The Ugly:
     *  Cache the image entities object privately, and expose a different 
     *  property that reassigns self every time.
     *  The Good:
     *  Firgure out when the object mutates (awake from fetch, or some other
     *  callback of CoreData) and invalidate the object there.
     */
    return [[self.imageEntitiesClass alloc] initWithModel:self];
}
```

This was working perfectly when we had the root MOC as main, and created children MOC on the fly to perform object mapping.

---

**backtrace:**

```
    frame #0: [...] CoreData`+[NSManagedObjectContext __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__] + 4
    frame #1: [...] CoreData`_sharedIMPL_pvfk_core + 221
  * frame #2: [...] Telly`Telly.TLYUserImages.feedAction.getter : Telly.TLYImageEntity(self=0x00007f84ca5cf6c0) + 416 at TLYUserImages.swift:26
    frame #3: [...] Telly`@objc Telly.TLYUserImages.feedAction.getter : Telly.TLYImageEntity + 34 at TLYUserImages.swift:0
    frame #4: [...] Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 251
    frame #5: [...] Foundation`-[NSArray(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 437
    frame #6: [...] Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 245
    frame #7: [...] Foundation`-[NSArray(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 435
    frame #8: [...] Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 261
    frame #9: [...] Foundation`-[NSArray(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 435
    frame #10: [...] Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 261
    frame #11: [...] Foundation`-[NSArray(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 435
    frame #12: [...] Telly`Telly.TLYMappingMeta.prefetch (target=AnyObject at 0x000000011e8ac858, self=0x00007f84ca423040)(forTarget : Swift.AnyObject) -> () + 361 at TLYMappingMeta.swift:75
    frame #13: [...] Telly`@objc Telly.TLYMappingMeta.prefetch (Telly.TLYMappingMeta)(forTarget : Swift.AnyObject) -> () + 54 at TLYMappingMeta.swift:0
    frame #14: [...] Telly`-[TLYMapTask _tag:with:using:in:](self=0x00007f84cecd64f0, _cmd=0x000000010aa12ee9, items=0x00007f84ca6d12e0, feedId=0x00007f84ce81ddf0, mapMeta=0x00007f84ca423040, moc=0x00007f84c9c89500) + 179 at TLYMapTask.m:42
    frame #15: [...] Telly`__39-[TLYMapTask _map:toMOC:sync:callback:]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=<unavailable>) + 1920 at TLYMapTask.m:127
    frame #16: [...] CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 201
    frame #17: [...] libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #18: 0x00000001107a76a7 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 2176
    frame #19: 0x00000001107a6cc0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 235
    frame #20: 0x00000001107aa3b9 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1359
    frame #21: 0x00000001107abb17 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
    frame #22: 0x0000000110b2d637 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 729
    frame #23: 0x0000000110b2b40d libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
```

---

ImageEntities.swift

```
import Foundation

/** Each model object is composed of an imageEntities subclass that
 *  holds the image entities associated with that model.
 */
class TLYImageEntities: NSObject {

    unowned let model: AnyObject

    init(model: AnyObject) {
        self.model = model
    }
}
```

Example subclass of `ImageEntities`. Notice how `self.user.avatarURL` access the MO subclass property:

TLYUserImages:

```
import Foundation

class TLYUserImages: TLYImageEntities {

    var user: TVUser {
        return model as! TVUser
    }

    lazy var profileHeader: TLYImageEntity = TLYImageEntity(
        listItem: self.user,
        imageURL: self.user.avatarURL,
        formatName: TLYImageFormatUserProfileHeader,
        processor: TVImageProcessor.avatarProcessor()
    )

    ...

}
```

TVUser+Aggregator, which provides the image entities class:

```
@implementation TVUser (Aggregator)

- (Class)imageEntitiesClass
{
    return [TLYUserImages class];
}

...

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `initWithModel:self` is called on an instance of a managed object subclass, it seems logical that the address changes. `self` refers to the instance variable, so whenever you call this with a different variable, the content of the arguments of your cryptic method will also be different. Perhaps your clever method to just insert a new object is a little bit too clever.

Maybe you should dispense with this hardly readable and evidently buggy method and do something more intuitive and straight-forward, like a class method that takes a context and returns a new object inserted into that context.

I would concur with the time-honored quote of the previous poster, Marcus S. Zarra:

> The mantra is the same. Keep the code simple. Do not be clever, do not be lazy. Do it right and it will be easy to maintain. Be clever or lazy and you are only punishing yourself and your users.

Comment: Sorry, your initial assumption is wrong, so I lost track of the rest of your answer. Technically, `initWithModel:` is a message sent to a `ImageEntity` instance. The MO subclass is passed in as an argument. I can add more code samples, and I am sure you'll change your mind about "being clever". It's ruthlessly simple, actually, and *very* readable.

Comment: OK, point well taken. Could yo post your `initWithModel` so we know what it actually does? -- With *readable*  I meant understandable, and apparently I am not the only reader that did not understand what it does.

Comment: Got it. I think it's my communication skills that are causing the confusion. Either case, I updated the question with the `ImageEntities` class.

Answer (score -1):

What does `[[self.imageEntitiesClass alloc] initWithModel:self]` do?  Specifically was does `-initWithModel:` do?  It is very strange to be calling an `alloc` `init` like that.

Looking into that method will help to determine what this interesting issue is.

Comment: I don't think there is anything strange here, just using some objc's dynamic features. ImageEntitiesClass returns the appropriate class from the subclass, then alloc initWithModel: simply initializes the object with the model as an "unowned" property: self.model = model

Comment: Now, that "model" property is ultimately just a copied pointer. The bug I am seeing tells me that the copied pointer is no longer referencing the same model this ImageEntities object is associated with. I'm in a middle of a refactor, but will try and provide more info soon.

Comment: It is unusual to hold onto a Class reference like that.  But you still don't show what is going on in the `-init...` method.  If there is anything interesting, it will probably be in there.

Comment: The class is just passed by the subclass, it's not unusual at all. Same way Apple uses `+[UIView layerClass]` so you can provide a custom layer class for your view. I added the implementation of `initWithModel:`, but because it's in swift, it looks a bit different than the ObjC version

Comment: Can you post the console output from the crash?  Looking for clues here as to why this is crashing.  BTW, what you are doing **IS** unusual.  Can't say that enough.  You are being way too clever.  It is one thing for Apple to build a class cluster, completely different for your code to being doing it.

Comment: I posted the backtrace from the multi-threaded assertion. I see your point. To me, clever code is just "clever lines of text", like `(5 ^ x++ ? x+log(1): --x)`. I don't have any of that, but I do have a slightly clever architecture. Now that is something I just passionately do throughout my projects. I think you are right, in the sense that when someone else comes in, they will either want to shoot me in the face, or blindly trust the code I've written.

Comment: The console output of the actual error is what I am looking for.  Not the stack trace.  What error was produced exactly?

Comment: I mentioned many times, it triggers core data multi-threaded assertions. "All that is left to us is honor".

Comment: Please post the exact text or close this question.  Generic "it crashed" comments are not solvable.

Comment: It's not my mistake that you are not aware of core data multi-threaded assertion. Did I ever say it crashed? It doesn't crash, please go read about it

Comment: Good luck with your issue.